# How can I open Sonos controller with search string

Tags: android, sonos

Is is possible to open the Sonos android Controller passing for example a search query that the controller will process and display results for?

For example:

```
    Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sonos.acr");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("artist:The%20Doors"));
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't support this today.  I will bring this up with the team as a possible future feature.

Comment: ....so the team wasn't into it then, was it?